# Trouble creating an object from self-defined classes

Tags: java, class, object

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public Date dob;
    public boolean sex;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname, Date dob, boolean sex){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname, Date dob, String s){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.dob = dob;
        if (s.charAt(0)=='f' || s.charAt(0)=='F') sex = true; else sex = false;
    }
```

Date.java

```
public class Date {
    public int day;
    public int month;
    public int year;

    public Date(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

Why is this wrong? How do I properly create an object? This is from a paper, so the classes above cannot be changed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person1 = new Person("Adeline", "Wells", (12,4,1992), false);
}
```

Comment: What is wrong? Please read this before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Note that the `Date` constructor you're using is deprecated and the entire `Date` class is obsolete (use `Instant` instead). Additionally, you're making two non-obvious gotchas by using a boolean: that the person's sex is known (and declared as male/female) and that one sex (male) maps to "true".

Comment: you are missing `new Date` in `..new Person(...` it should be `..."Wells", new Date(12,4,1992)...`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that yours field date into person class is a class as well, so you do in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Date d = new Date(12,4,1992);
     Person person1 = new Person("Aaron", "Wells", d, false);
}
```

Otherwise if you want pass directly day month and year you can do somenthig like this:

```
public Person(String firstname, String lastname, int d, int m, int y, boolean sex){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.dob = new Date(d, m, y);
        this.sex = sex;
    }
```

and then now you can do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person1 = new Person("Adeline", "Wells", 12,4,1992, false);
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there absolutely no way to put them all in one line?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person1 = new Person("Aaron", "Wells", new Date(12,4,1992), false);
}
```